# Lagrange multiplier for three unknown and two constraints

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I was stuck with finding lagrange multiplier for the following problem:
$f(x,y,z)=xyz^2$ with constraints $g_1(x,y,z)=8x+y-9z^2-10=0$ and $g_2(x,y,z)=3x+4y^2-z-12=0$.
I was able to get these equations with five unknowns where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the multipliers.

$yz^2-8\lambda-3\mu=0$

$xz^2-\lambda-2\mu y=0$

$2xyz+18\lambda z+\mu=0$

$8x+y-9z^2 =10$

$3x+4y^2-z=12$ 
I am not able to get past this in finding the variables.

Comment: You want to find max or min?

Comment: I would like to find min.